# glPushAttrib/glPopAttrib stack implementation in GLES

Tags: opengl-es

GLES2 does not support glPush***/glPop***. Does anyone know if there is an implementation of a state stack for OpenGL ES 2.0? Any solution to my problem is welcome.

Comment: The programmable pipeline is so much more flexible, why are you trying to restrain yourself?

Answer (score 2):

glPushAttrib/glPopAttrib managed fixed-function state that was not moved over from the older versions of OpenGL.  Programmable shaders replaced all of the fixed-function functionality in GLES, and newer versions of OpenGL.

State is now something you manage yourself via inputs to shader programs.

Comment: That may be true, however some states are still kicking around: Scissor, Depth, Stencil, Culling, Blending.

Comment: That's true, and those wouldn't be handled by shader inputs either.  Most big projects handle state changes manually anyway because changing state can be a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a quick solution, you may be interested in [this library](http://boards.openpandora.org/index.php/topic/11506-opengl-implementation-tldr-more-games/) ([Github repository](https://github.com/lunixbochs/glshim)). It only emulates small subset of OpenGL 1.x, glPush*/glPop* included. Note, that mentioned project is still very much WIP, so don't expect everything to work out of box.